# Have a confirmation on launching an app

Tags: applications

I'm looking for a way to control other apps opening: Before opening an app, I would receive a dialog box before asking me if I would really open the application then I can say no and I'm less addict. I'm not looking for something that will block other application usage, only show a pop up with a dialog.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). I've rephrased your question to avoid it from being closed (3 votes on that already); it should still match your intention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an app that does exactly that, but you can use any app lock for this.

Take for example this [app lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) download it, and set the code to be the number 5 (example) now, go to the app lock settings > password settings > password hint. Change the hint to say something like "are you sure you want to use this app? Press 5 for "yes", or exit for "no".

Then, select which apps you want this dialogue to appear on by going to "app lock" and press on the + symbol. After you add the desired apps, you'll see an option called "fake" this will be an even better reminded not to use it. Basically if you choose this option, what will happen is, when you open the blocked apps, it will say that the app crashed, and only after long pressing on "ok" will it open the keypad.